# In a 3d array in numpy. How can I extract indices of max element in third dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

Example input 3D array of shape (2,2,2):

```
[[[ 1, 2],
  [ 4, 3]],
 [[ 5, 6],
  [ 8, 7]]]
```

My 3d array has a shape of (N, N, N), in above example N = 2.

I need to get all indices such that index for third dimension belongs to max element in third dimension, Output for above 3D array:

```
[[0, 0, 1],  # for element 2
 [0, 1, 0],  # for element 4
 [1, 0, 1],  # for element 6
 [1, 1, 0]]  # for element 8
```

It would be great if I can do that with `argmax` or `argwhere` function. I want to avoid iteration and see if its possible to do this using numpy functions.

Comment: How does 6 get mapped into [1, 0, 1]? I don't understand the output you want.

Comment: @YXD so in this 3d array "6" is in (1)st 2d array , then in that (1)st 2d array "6" is at location (0,1)  :  giving me (1, 0, 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to get all the indices along the first and second axes and then stacking them alongwith the max indices from the third axis using [`np.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)  -

```
d = a.argmax(-1)
m,n = a.shape[:2]
c,r = np.mgrid[:m,:n]
out = np.column_stack((c.ravel(),r.ravel(),d.ravel()))
```

Sample run -

```
In [96]: a
Out[96]: 
array([[[38, 49, 15, 61, 29],
        [31, 88, 45, 88, 20],
        [17, 97, 58, 61, 14],
        [43, 77, 56, 92, 89]],

       [[48, 91, 49, 35, 58],
        [53, 34, 58, 92, 52],
        [20, 35, 70, 41, 81],
        [60, 42, 85, 82, 41]],

       [[45, 41, 32, 41, 25],
        [59, 32, 90, 18, 47],
        [24, 93, 29, 89, 12],
        [80, 27, 12, 51, 33]]])

In [97]: out
Out[97]: 
array([[0, 0, 3],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 3],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 2],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 0]])
```

---

Alternatively, since those indices are basically repetitions, we can use `np.repeat` and `np.tile` to get those indices arrays and then use `np.column_stack` as before, like so -

```
d0 = np.arange(m).repeat(n)
d1 = np.tile(np.arange(n),m)
out = np.column_stack((d0,d1,d.ravel()))
```